# Probability of the same number winning AT LEAST two times in a 1/100 000 lottery after 200 executions. [SOLVED]

Tags: probability

In a lottery with numbers from 0 to 99999 what is the probability that after 200 executions of the experiment the same number wins at least 2 times?

The only idea I had so far was to calculate the probability of getting said number at most 1 time and take that away from 1.

$$1-\binom{200}{0}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{100000}{1}}^{0}\cdot \left ( 1-\frac{1}{\binom{100000}{1}} \right )^{200}-\binom{200}{1}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{100000}{1}}^{1}\cdot \left ( 1-\frac{1}{\binom{100000}{1}} \right )^{199} = 1.99 \times 10^{-6}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe the answer should instead be $$1-\frac{200!\binom{100000}{200}}{100000^{200}}\approx0.1805586629$$considering you appear to have used a Binomial model which is not valid.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thank you. You are selecting the 200 different numbers that win each lottery by using $\binom{100000}{200}$ and then calculate their probability as $\frac{200}{100000}\cdot \frac{199}{100000}\cdot ... \cdot \frac{1}{100000}$.  Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Yes. One can also just interpret this as just choosing $200$ numbers in any order and hence the multiplication by $200!$.